# How to iterate/parse Tweepy get_user object

Tags: python, tweepy

In playing around with Tweepy I notice that the 'status' variable returned from a call to get_user is `<tweepy.models.Status object at 0x02AAE050>`

Sure, I can call get_user.USER.status, but how can I grab that information from the get_user call? i.e. I want to loop through user.**getstate**() and if I find an object which requires further iteration, loop through that too

I've searched high/low of answers, but my newness to Python is causing problems, which I'm pretty sure are easy to solve if I knew the right questions to ask.

Thanks for any pointer here...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

import tweepy
import json

from pprint import pprint


api = tweepy.API()



def main():
    print "Starting."

    user = api.get_user('USER',include_entities=1)

    print "================ type ================="
    print type(user)

    print "================ dir ================="
    print dir(user)

    print "================ user ================="
    #
    # We can see 'status': <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x02AAE050>, .......but how do I "explode" that automagically?
    #
    pprint ((user).__getstate__())



    print "================ user.status ================="
    pprint ((user).status.__getstate__())

    print "================= end ================="





if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I was able to get the intended behaviour by using jsonpickle, using the following code.

```
import jsonpickle
.
.
.
user = api.get_user('USERNAME',include_entities=1)
    pickled = jsonpickle.encode(user)
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(pickled), indent=4, sort_keys=True))   #you could just  print pickled, but this makes it pretty
```

I'm still really interested to understand what I'm missing in understanding how to detect and expand that status object.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

api = tweepy.API(auth,parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

user = api.get_user('USER',include_entities=1)

now you can user user['status'] and others easily